# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GlobalVariables", referenced from: objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a Singleton so I can use a variable globally but I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GlobalVariables", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Some solutions to this problem suggest adding a third-party library in build phases, but I don't know which library to add. Here is my Singleton class:

.h

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject

@property BOOL *MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW;

+ (GlobalVariables*)sharedInstance;

@end
```

.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "GlobalVariables.h"


@implementation GlobalVariables

@synthesize MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (GlobalVariables*)sharedInstance {
    static GlobalVariables *obj = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        obj = [[self alloc] init];
        [obj loadVariables];
    });
    return obj;
}

- (void)loadVariables {

        self.MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW = NO;
}

@end
```

This is how I am trying to access the MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW variable from MapViewController:

```
 [GlobalVariables sharedInstance].MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW
```

Comment: `MapViewController.h` (or `MapViewController.m`), doe they have `#import "GlobalVariables.h"` ? And what's the class of `MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW`? Really a `BOOL` (because it's declared as a pointer in your code, but in `loadVariables` you don't seem to treat it as such.

Comment: Yes I had, I also #import "GlobalVariables.h" to .pch file

Comment: You don't need `@synthesize` and that ivar should not be a `BOOL *`, but just a `BOOL.   I'd also suggest naming the properties in the standard fashion;  `mapSatelliteViewEnabled`.

Comment: Thank you @bbum for your valuable input.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. On the .m file in xcode  at the right, I had to tick the checkbox of the Target Membership.

Comment: You are the Best 'student' :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure "GlobalVariables" is add in "Compile Sources". Build phases->Compile Source and add the file.